# Put link/button in email to reply to sender on website

Tags: webforms

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how this is meant to work. What I'm trying to achieve is as follows:

1) I've got Webform module installed and working. Just has generic fields for now.

2) What I want it to do is as follows:

User A wants fills in the form (webform) asking for a quote to clean their 3 bedroom house. This form gets submitted and cleaning companies get notified by email. - **This bit I have figured out!**

BUT - What I want to happen is that when the cleaning companies receive this email (name, number of bedrooms etc) I want there to be a link within the email that allows the cleaning company to click on that takes them to another form on the website where they can enter quote information (like price, imagery etc). When the cleaning company clicks submit the original user A gets notified a quote has come in.

Any ideas how I set this up? It doesn't appear to be included in the standard module.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this from webform alone.  I would create a custom form (using Form API in a custom module) with a path that includes a parameter to identify the original webform submission.  Something like /quote-response/{webform-submission}.  The "response form" then queries the webform submission to get the email of the person who submitted the original quote request.  Keep in mind if this route doesn't require any authentication, you could be opening yourself up to bots / malicious users, so I recommend implementing some additional security / verification.